# Store pdf remote file in postgres DB with php

Tags: php, database, postgresql, pdf, file-upload

I have little pdf (or txt, odt, doc) file to be store in Postgres DB with php.
I use this php functions to read file:

```
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

$content = fread($fp, filesize($name));

$content = addslashes($content);

fclose($fp);
```

and then try to store in db:

```
$sql = "insert into Table(column) values ('$content'::bytea)";

$result = @pg_query($sql);
```

"column" is bytea type.

When I execute the script with pdf file, I get the follow error:

```
ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe2e3cf HINT: This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding".
```

When I execute the script with doc file, I get the follow error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type bytea
```

When I execute the script with txt file, NO error:

What's wrong and what is the proper way to store files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `pg_escape_string` instead of `addslashes`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php

Comment: Thanks, pg_escape_bytea() instead of addslashes() is exactly what I wanted.